# keychains usage (for separation free/nonfree version)

Tags: ios, objective-c, keychain

I'm new with keychains and trying to separate my app content with it.

For setting a type of version I'm using this code

```
KeychainItemWrapper *keychain = [[KeychainItemWrapper alloc] initWithIdentifier:@"TestUDID" accessGroup:nil];
[keychain setObject:@"free" forKey:(__bridge id)kSecAttrAccount];
```

And getting like this

```
KeychainItemWrapper *keychain = [[KeychainItemWrapper alloc] initWithIdentifier:@"TestUDID" accessGroup:nil];    
NSLog(@"%@",[keychain objectForKey:(__bridge id)kSecAttrAccount]);
```

So, every time I need to check an app version, I should create a keychain wrapper object and get object for key. How can I simplify it?

I'm thinking about a creating global bool variable. There are any better approaches?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Global variables like in your example is harmful. Your app becomes messy (especially in multi-threading). Use global variable only for constants.
Create a class with static methods (or singleton if you want store properties), for example, `AppInfo` where you will put information about the app.

```
// AppInfo.h
@interface AppInfo : NSObject

// (class) available in Xcode 8
@property (class) id appVersion;

@end

// AppInfo.m
@implementation AppInfo 

+ (KeychainItemWrapper *)keychain {
  return [[KeychainItemWrapper alloc] initWithIdentifier:@"TestUDID" accessGroup:nil];
}

+ (NSString *)appVersion {
  return [self.keychain objectForKey:(__bridge id)kSecAttrAccount];
}

+ (void)setAppVersion:(NSString *)appVersion {
  [self.keychain setObject:appVersion forKey:(__bridge id)kSecAttrAccount];
}

@end
```